# Why columns are of different height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I used a single function to retrieve all the items from database with some bootstrap styles. In CSS I specified size of images as follows: `width: 100%; height: auto;`.

But something strange happens, first and third images are of the size 247x247 while second and fourth are 247*192.79.

I want all of them to have **equal height**, how can I fix this?

[image: columns of different size]

Comment: Provide images that all have identical aspect ratio.

Comment: You can do it by `width: 247px; height 247px; object-fit: cover;`.

Comment: @SatoTakeru I see, thanks this solution is ok)